# Resource groups are not working in gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm attempting to queue all pipelines being merged to the master branch. I can see that when I merge the pipelines at the same time, they are running in parallel, which is not the expected behavior for resource groups. In this example the resourse group named `uninterruptible`

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
stages:
  - .pre
  - pre_check
  - build
  - assign_test
  - host_test
  - deploy

workflow:
  rules:
    # Disable those non-protected push triggered pipelines
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^release\/v/ && $CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ /^v\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?($|-)/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: never
    # when running merged result pipelines, it would create a temp commit id. use $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA instead of $CI_COMMIT_SHA.
    # Please use PIPELINE_COMMIT_SHA at all places that require a commit sha
    - if: $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS != null
      variables:
        PIPELINE_COMMIT_SHA: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA
    - if: $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS == null
      variables:
        PIPELINE_COMMIT_SHA: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - when: always

before_script:
  - echo "Before script is started here"

default:
  interruptible: true
  retry:
    max: 2
    when:
      - always

include:
  - '.gitlab/ci/.pre.yml'
  - '.gitlab/ci/pre_check.yml'
  - '.gitlab/ci/build.yml'
  - '.gitlab/ci/assign_test.yml'
  - '.gitlab/ci/host_test.yml'
  - '.gitlab/ci/deploy.yml'
```

`.pre.yml`

```yaml
uninterruptible_job:
  stage: .pre
  interruptible: false
  environment: fake
  resource_group: uninterruptible
  script:
    - echo "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is uninterruptible"
  tags:
    - assign_test
  rules:
    - if:  '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^release\/v/'
      when: always
```

Comment: Are you sure that the same _job_ (`uninterruptible_job`) in each pipeline is actually running/executing concurrently? Keep in mind resource groups control concurrency for jobs, not entire pipelines.

Comment: At this point, the jobs are not running concurrently. They are both running in parallel which in not  expected to be. Same thing seems working for other but not for me. Not sure What I am doing wrong https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/194023#note_928958193